# Forwarding to /index.php in IIS

Tags: php, .htaccess, iis, web-config

My client is using an IIS webhosting service that (annoyingly) doesn't recognize `index.php` as a default document. I've written a simple `index.html` that `<meta>` refreshes the page to `index.php`, but is there a way to do what I'd normally do in a `.htaccess` document in IIS?

For example, can I write a `web.config` document that does the following and drop it in root, like I would a `.htaccess`?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/index.php [L,R=301]
```

I don't have any other access than FTP.

Comment: I seem to recall IIS used to use `Default.asp`, so might it be configured with similar for PHP - `Default.php` maybe?

Comment: [Possible solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522057/how-to-set-web-config-default-page-for-php-index-file)

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <add value="index.php" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

in your `web.config`